# moving code from Python to R (keras/TF)

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to port over the following code from Python to R. I'm not sure if there is such thing as a function similar to `lambda()`. The closest I could think of was `function()` though the result is not what I'm seeking.

```
def combine_estimates(data):
    estimates, coefs = data
    return K.sum(estimates * coefs, axis=-1)

result = Lambda(combine_estimates)([estimates_input, coefs])
```

I tried something like this in R:

```
combineEst <- function(data) {
  x <- K$sum(data[[1]] * data[[2]], axis = -1L)
  }
result <- combineEst(list(estimates_input, coefs))
```

Comment: You need to add   'return(x)'  before the last curly bracket to get an output from function.. Another thing, What does the K$ mean in this code? In python code it should be a library that includes the sum function...But in R ? I don't get it...

Comment: Are you sure the python code works? What is the capital, `Lambda`? What is `K`? WPlease post all `import` lines.